# Turning a Trigger Into a Compound Trigger?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, triggers

How do I turn the following simple trigger into a **compound trigger** so as to avoid the `ORA-04091 table is mutating error`?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER grades_before_update
BEFORE UPDATE OF grade_percent
ON grades
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
     grade_percent_var  NUMBER;
BEGIN
     SELECT  grade_percent
     INTO    grade_percent_var
     FROM    grades
     WHERE   student_id = :new.student_id;    

     IF (grade_percent_var > 100 OR grade_percent_var < 0) THEN
          RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20001, 'grade percent must be between 0 and 100');
     END IF;
END;
/
```

The reason I'm asking is because every time I test this trigger using an `UPDATE` query like:

```
UPDATE grades
SET grade_percent = 90
WHERE student_id = 1;
```

I get the `ORA-04091 table is mutating error`.  I've searched it up and this site says that I'd need a compound trigger to avoid this error:

[Using Triggers](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/triggers.htm#LNPLS2006)

But I don't know how to start.

Comment: Is your goal to check the value of the field `grade_percent` before the update?

Comment: Yes.  And triggers must be used.  It's part of the requirements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a compound trigger for that you just need to check the current value. That error is because you are selecting the table you are updating and this is an invalid operation (for a before trigger).

So you just need to access the value of that field the same way you did with the `:new.student_id`

It would be:

```
IF (:NEW.grade_percent > 100 OR :NEW.grade_percent < 0) THEN
      RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20001, 'grade percent must be between 0 and 100');
END IF;
```

There is no need to declare any variables nor the select statement. The `:NEW.grade_percent` is the value that was used in the `update` command.